# Will GitLab docker executor open login shells?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I've installed GitLab's omnibus installer as a docker container, as well as the GitLab runner in another container. I registered the runner to use the docker executor with a default image that I've built on top of Ubuntu 18.04.

The image that I've built has rvm and nvm for installing different versions of Ruby and Node. However, when GitLab tries to run my CI pipeline on that image, it can't launch the `rvm` or `nvm` commands.

```
$ nvm install $NODE_VERSION
bash: line 115: nvm: command not found
```

I think the default installation of both rvm and nvm require you to launch a login shell, in order to make the `rvm` and `nvm` commands available.

After a bunch of messing with `.bashrc`, I got the `rvm` command to work, but is there a way to just make the CI pipelines launch in login shells?

Is there a way to dump the exact command that the GitLab runner is using to launch the CI pipeline? I think I found the [source code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/qa/qa/service/docker_run/gitlab_runner.rb), but it would be nice to just dump the docker command arguments. I tried setting the [`log_level`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section) to `debug`, but I didn't notice any difference.